# How can I transform dots to line between CSS menu items?

Tags: html, css, menu, menuitem

I have CSS vertical menu and I want to make dots between shapes like this photo

http://s15.postimg.org/vz4jok3wr/Untitled_2.jpg

We can see line from Home to ABOUT and from ABOUT to Games(current item) I need when I choose programs this dots transform to line , and when I choose Home or any item above lines transform to dots and etc.... ,

```
<style>
body{background-color:#000;}
ul,
ul li,
ul li a { margin-bottom:30px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:#999;
  margin-left:20px;
}
.active { color:#F00;}

*, *:before, *:after{ 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
} 
.css-shapes-preview{ 
    position: relative; 
    height: 10px; 
    width: 10px; 
    background-color: #428bca; 
    border-radius: 150px; 
}
</style>
   <ul>
      <li class="css-shapes-preview"><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li class="css-shapes-preview"><a href='#'><span>ABOUT</span></a></li>
      <li class="css-shapes-preview"><a href='#' class="active"><span>GAMES</span></a></li>
      <li class="css-shapes-preview"><a href='#'><span>SONGS</span></a></li>
      <li class="css-shapes-preview"><a href='#'><span>PROGRAMS</span></a></li>
      <li class="css-shapes-preview"><a href='#'><span>DESIGNS</span></a></li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: This is not defined in the few lines you posted above. Can you please add an example to jsfiddle.net of your code. Or try to search your CSS/JS for `dashed`

Comment: What ever css your using to create them isn't in the css you have posted above not even solid lines and without seeing what is adding it its nearly impossible to help

Comment: I search for this idea and find this site make this menu [link](http://www.luxaqua-design.com/) what i want but i can't find how to make it tried a lot of codes and create anthers but same result .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating a new element (you can use a pseudo-element in this case to keep your markup semantic) and giving it a dotted border. See an example at http://jsfiddle.net/74yav8h9/. The relevant CSS is:

```
ul:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 5px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    /* red for visibility, you can obviously make whatever color you want */
    border-left: 2px dotted red; 
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i need when i chose (GAMES) item all above of it transform to lines and all of down it transform to dots not active item only

Comment: For that you'll likely need to attach a class to every item that needs a solid line below it. Then, instead of making the border be on the `ul:before` element, put it on the `li:before` element. Make it only the height between 2 elements, and if the given element specifies it should be solid you make that line solid. Don't have time at the moment to put the jsfiddle together, but give that a shot.

Comment: tried it but no effect :( ..... i search for this idea and find this site make this menu [link](http://www.luxaqua-design.com/) maybe that will help ,regard :)